# Using bootstrap in jupyter widget

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I try to make simple widget with animation for Jupyter notebook using ipywidgets library.

I want to use bootstrap library for prettify my widget. So, I imported `bootstrap.min.css` file, but, when I create widget, styles of my notebook break down. Please see screenshot before
[image: before]

and after creating widget.

[image]

Apparently this is due to the fact that styles are overwritten. What can I do to correct the influence of my styles on the general jupyter-notebook styles. I would be grateful for any advice or example of how bootstrap is used in other widgets.

Comment: Jupyter ships with Bootstrap installed. Try not importing it.

Comment: @stever Jupyter contains old version of bootstrap (3.X), can I use the new version?